# Python Query (Lottery project)

Tags: python-2.x

I have a query relating to return only the last results, so here is my code:

```
   import random

    def Step_1():
        Start_Game = raw_input("Enter \'Start' to continue \n") 
        if Start_Game == 'start':                              
            print "Let the Lottery begin"
        else:
            return Step_1()
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    def Step_2():
            random_list = []
            for i in range(10):
                while len(random_list) < 6:
                    random_number = random.randint(1,59)
                    while random_number not in random_list:
                         random_list.append(random_number) 
                         print random_list
Step_1()
Step_2()
```

When i run this it gives me the below result,

```
Enter 'Start' to continue 
start
Let the Lottery begin
[56]
[56, 20]
[56, 20, 32]
[56, 20, 32, 2]
[56, 20, 32, 2, 23]
[56, 20, 32, 2, 23, 30]
```

However how can i just display the last result generated and discard the previous 5. I know i need to change the last bit "print" within my Step_2 function, but what do I need to add?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

To make your `Step_2` function only print the final version of the list, you can simply move the `print` statement outside the loops (unindenting it). But you have two more loops than you really need, so you can simplify things a bit more:

```
def Step_2():
    random_list = []
    while len(random_list) < 6:     # the for loop didn't do anything useful, delete it
        random_number = random.randint(1,59)
        if random_number not in random_list:     # use an if instead of another while loop
            random_list.append(random_number) 
    print random_list     # unindent this line so it only prints when the loop is done
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help!!! Works perfectly fine, not sure why i did not think of that at the start :))!